# NSIS installer for chrome extension out put error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, nsis

I am trying to compile an installer for my chrome extension using the following script :

```
     Processing script file: "C:\Documents and Settings\My-PC\Bureau\1.nsi"
     !define: "PRODUCT_VERSION"="7.0.0"
     !define: "CRXNAME"="1.crx"
     !define: "CRXID"="phogkfodcfpcnalkmlcjmlnhgjacapcf"
     !define: "INSTALL_DIR"="$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\phogkfodcfpcnalkmlcjmlnhgjacapcf\7.0.0_0"
      !define: "P_FILE"="$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
      Function: ".onInit"
      SetSilent: silent
       FunctionEnd
```

However when trying to compile it, it show me this error "Processed 1 file, writing output:
Error: invalid script: never had OutFile command Error - aborting creation process"
Can any one tell me where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Every script needs at least the OutFile command and one section. OutFile defines the name of the created installer e.g.

```
OutFile myInstaller.exe
```

Comment: Can you provide a tutorial to the structure of section ?

Comment: Well, do you have any code yet (apart from what you posted above) that will actually install your extension. That code would go inside a section. If you decide installing without the use of a section (e.g. using the `.onInit` function, you still have to declare an empty section. Have a look at these [examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials) for clarification.